# List folder permission doesn't show subfolders

Tags: windows, permissions, ntfs, network-shares, shared-folders

I have situation described below.

```
Z:\SHARE (shared | Everyone Read\Change) Authenticated users group has NTFS permission "List folder contents"
Z:\SHARE\Foo Only john.doe has permission to enter that directory
Z:\SHARE\Bar Only alan.smith has permission to enter that directory
```

The problem is when Joe or Alan enter the share they see only that folder to which they have permission to enter.

Shouldn't they see both folders, cause of Authenticated users permission?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason of that problem was Access-based enumeration. It is enabled so users can see only folders which they have direct access to.